# Select HTML content using PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the paragraphs under this tag:

[image: Here's an image]

I tried to:

```
<?php

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile("https://sabq.org/xMQjz2");

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');

    if (!is_null($elements)) {

        foreach ($elements as $element) {

            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                  echo $node->textContent. "\n";
            }
        } 
   }

?>
```

And I got the paragraphs I wanted along with unwanted ones, and they were duplicated.

**EDIT:**
I changed the URL, hope it works

Comment: I'm getting 403 forbidden when trying to load that URL, so I can't test it, but have you tried $elements = $doc->getElementById('dev-content');  See reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Yes, I did. Here's a shorter link https://sabq.org/xMQjz2 hope it works

Answer (score 0):

The link that you have provided throws an error when accessing it so what I did, I found a function that could get the contents of the webpage using curl instead of the DOMDocument class which you were using.

I used preg_match and regex to extract the specific element that you were looking for.

Here's the code:

```
    <?php

    //opened url
    $content = get_fcontent("https://sabq.org/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%A3%D9%84%D9%81-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%8A-%D9%82%D8%B5%D8%B5-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B0-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%8A");

    //extract specific html tag and its innerHTML
    preg_match('/<p .*? ng\-bind\-html\=\"getContent\(material\.content\)\" .*?>.*?<\/p>/m', $content[0], $matches);

    //display the wanted element
    echo $matches[0];

    //getting contents using curl because threw error: failed to open stream
    function get_fcontent( $url,  $javascript_loop = 0, $timeout = 5 ) {
        $url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

        $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close ( $ch );

        if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302) {
            ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");

            if ( $headers = get_headers($response['url']) ) {
                foreach( $headers as $value ) {
                    if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                        return get_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
                }
            }
        }

    if (    ( preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) || preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value) ) && $javascript_loop < 5) {
        return get_url( $value[1], $javascript_loop+1 );
    } else {
        return array( $content, $response );
    }
}
?>
```

For testing, I created a local file called test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This should not be showing.</p>
<p  ng-bind-html="getContent(material.content)" id="dev-content" class="details-text">This is a test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the local url http://localhost/example/test.html instead of the link you provided for testing purposes.

And from the local file I created for testing, I got the following result:

```
<p  ng-bind-html="getContent(material.content)" id="dev-content" class="details-text">This is a test.</p>
```

Here's the result that I got from the original url:

```
<p  ng-bind-html="getContent(material.content)" id="dev-content" class="details-text"></p>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: it's not working, the code results empty page. Plus I want to get the text between <p></p>

Comment: I tried it myself using the website and I checked that the p tag you are referring to doesn't contain any text probably why it returns the p tags only. I duplicated the page locally, added text in between p tags, and tested it, it returned something. Can you please put your code in codepen or something similar so that I can take a look?

Comment: Perhaps because my website is using AngularJS to load data. Here's a shorter link if you may take a look https://sabq.org/xMQjz2

Comment: @user3463199, I looked into the source code of your live site, the tag <p  ng-bind-html="getContent(material.content)" id="dev-content" class="details-text"></p> doesn't contain anything. Perhaps you are referring to other dev-content paragraph tags?